# if I use TLS when sip communicate in two endpoint, is TLS encrypt both SIP and RTP?

Tags: ssl, sip, rtp, dtls

I am sip client developer, I confuse TLS concept.
our sip client communicate using TLS.

at that time,  TLS encrypt just only SIP,  or encrypt both SIP and RTP?

my coworker says TLS only encrypt only SIP, and   RTP encrypted by SRTP...

is this right SIP- > TLS,  RTP -> SRTP?

and

DTLS is same?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/), [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Actually, if you _develop_ a SIP client like stated here it is relevant for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS only encrypts the SIP part and also only hop-by-hop (e.g. peer#1 to SIP proxy to peer#2) and not end-to-end. It might exchange keys for SRTP within the SIP messages, so RTP will be secured too, but SRTP itself is not using TLS but the symmetric keys exchanged within the SIP dialog.

And DTLS is just TLS with datagram instead of streaming, e.g. with TLS you use SIP over TCP and put a TLS layer on top, while DTLS can be used with UDP.

Comment: I have one more question..for  exchange key for SRTP...  if A client send offer to B include key(fingerprint) so is this key encode A client RTP(A -> B) or B client RTP (B -> A)

Comment: The key is for the offered connection. Because the SDP from A to B contains the offer for RTP transfer from B to A the key is also for this transfer.

Comment: I am confuse.  client B encode rtp using client A fingerprint. is it right?      client B receive from fingerprint from A.  and encode rtp using received fingerprint. and send data to A.. wrong?

Comment: A "fingerprint" is usually the name for a hash, but in this case you transfer a master key which is then used to derive the key used in encryption. And yes, client B receives the SDP from A, which contains the information how to send the (S)RTP to a, including the master key for the encryption. It might help to take a look at http://genesysguru.com/blog/blog/2011/09/14/implementing-secure-voice-using-secure-rtp-srtp/ to understand the process.